# Find available ids lower than 500 vis dscl

Tags: macos, terminal, users

How can we write a script around dscl to loop over the currently listed IDs in use and then spit out the first id under 500 that is not in use yet?

### Update # 1 (Feb 17th 2013)

I found some very helpful scripts on http://wiki.awkwardtv.org/wiki/Manage_users_and_groups_scripts which I was able to water down to the point where I could get the first available ID higher than a given number but I still don't have a way of scripting it to stop looking beyond a certain upper limit like 500.

```
#!/bin/sh
continue="no"
number_used="dontknow"
fnumber=300
user_id=0
until [ $continue = "yes" ] ; do
  if [ `dscl . -list /Users UniqueID | awk '{print $2, "\t", $1}' | sort -ug | grep -c "$fnumber"` -gt 0 ] ; then
    number_used=true
  else
    number_used=false
  fi
  if [ $number_used = "true" ] ; then
    fnumber=`expr $fnumber + 1`
  else
    user_id="$fnumber"
    continue="yes"
  fi
done;
echo "Next available user_id: $user_id"
```

### Update # 2 (Feb 17th 2013)

I suppose I could work backwards but still what if every userid from 500 to 0 is taken? I still need to set a lowerbound to get out of a messy negative ID situation.

```
#!/bin/sh
continue="no"
number_used="dontknow"
fnumber_work_backwards_from=500
fnumber=$fnumber_work_backwards_from
user_id=0
until [ $continue = "yes" ] ; do
  if [ `dscl . -list /Users UniqueID | awk '{print $2, "\t", $1}' | sort -ug | grep -c "$fnumber"` -gt 0 ] ; then
    number_used=true
  else
    number_used=false
  fi
  if [ $number_used = "true" ] ; then
    fnumber=`expr $fnumber - 1`
  else
    user_id="$fnumber"
    continue="yes"
  fi
done;
echo "First available user_id which is closest to and lower than $fnumber_work_backwards_from: $user_id"
```

Comment: Did you see my answer when you updated the question? (I undeleted it, maybe it didn't show up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with Ruby, for example, which is much more concise than any Bash script you could possibly find for this.

```
dscl . -list /Users UniqueID | awk '{print $2}' | 
ruby -e 'puts ((0..500).to_a - STDIN.readlines.map(&:to_i)).first'
```

We simply subtract the actual IDs (as an array) from another array consisting of the numbers 0 through 500. This gives us all unused IDs in an array, and from that we take the first, since it's already sorted.

Comment: Not a language I can use in my infrastructure but you answered the Q :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, sorry. OS X comes with Ruby though, or can't you use it for some other reason? Note that going with a set-based approach is often easier than lower level stuff—problem domain thinking, so to say :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work to find what you need. The function `find_next_userid` below will search between two numbers, inclusively, to find the first unused userid. For your case, just use `0` and `499`, shown below. The function returns an empty string if it couldn't find any empty slots, so you need to check for that before using the `echo`ed value (shown below as well).

<strike>I realize this does not use dscl, but</strike> this should work and be more portable. [Update: Added version using dscl.]

Technically, I am using bash, so I have noted that; I'm not sure if would work in sh or not.

Tested on OS X 10.9.4.

```
#!/bin/bash
user_exists()
{
    username=$1

    if id -u $username >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        return 0
    else
        return -1
    fi
}

user_exists_dscl()
{
    username=$1

    user_found=`dscl . -search /Users UniqueID $username | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $1}'`
    if [ "${user_found}" != "" ] ; then
        return 0
    else
        return -1
    fi
}

find_next_userid()
{
    low=$1
    hi=$2

    for curr in `seq $low $hi`;
    do
        if ! (user_exists $curr) ; then
            echo $curr
            break
        fi
    done

    echo ""
}

FIRST_UNUSED_USERID=`find_next_userid 0 499`

if [ "$FIRST_UNUSED_USERID" != "" ]; then
    echo "Do your stuff here!"
else
    echo "No unused userid found!"
fi
```

Edit: Forgot to include `user_exists()`. Updated to note that this solution doesn't use dscl but still works. I think I might have a solution using dscl shortly.

Edit 2: Added `user_exists_dscl`. Replace calls to `user_exists` with `user_exists_dscl` if you really really need to use `dscl` instead of `id`.